# can we hash the JWT and save the hashed version in local storage since it is not safe to put the jwt in local storage?

Tags: jwt, web-deployment

since it is not safe to keep the JWT in local storage because of CSRF or XSS attacks so i am wondering is it possible for example to create a hash function that can hash the JWT and keep the hashed version (useless) in local storage? and we create also a decode function that decode the hashed JWT and return the correct JWT whenever we need to use it.
it seems something manageable to me could there be any possible flaws or issues related to this technique?

Comment: In general, most patterns do not involve storing the JWT, which largely defeats the purpose of using JWT.  You may have a design problem here.

Comment: if that hashed version can be decoded, CSRF or XSS attacks can also decode it.

Comment: The explicit purpose of a hash function is, that it is *one way*, so you cannot get the original data from the hash value. Any function that is reversable can also be revered by your attacker.

Comment: Please be careful with the terms you're using. When you encrypt something, it can be decrypted, (with a key) when you encode something, it can be decoded, and when you hash something, there's no way back. You can't hash and then decode, this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty pointless to hash the JWT.

A better approach is to use the BFF pattern as described in these two resources

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)
- [The BFF Pattern (Backend for Frontend): An Introduction](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf)

Comment: Thank you these resources are very helpful